# If a REST web service call fails, should a message or event queue be used to retry later?

Tags: java, web-services, json, rest, message-queue

I'm building a web service with a RESTful interface (lets call it **MY_API**). This service relies on another RESTful webservice to handle certain aspects (calling it **OTHER_API**). I'd like to determine what types of best practices I should consider using to handle failures of OTHER_API.

### Scenario

My UI is a single page javascript application. There are some fairly complex actions a user can take, which can easily take the user a minute or two to complete. When they are done, they click the SAVE button and MY_API is called to save the data.

MY_API has everything it needs to persist the information submitted by the user. However, there is an action that must take place that is handled by OTHER_API. For instance, OTHER_API might handle sending out an emails. Or perhaps it handles adding line items to my user's billing statement. In both cases, these are critical things than must be completed, but they don't have to happen *right now*, they just need to happen *eventually*.

If OTHER_API fails, I don't want to simply tell the user their action has failed, as they spent a lot of time doing it and this will make the experience less than optimal.

### Questions

- So should I create some sort of Message or Event Queue that can save these failed REST requests to OTHER_API and process them later?
- Any advice or suggestions on techniques to go about saving REST requests for delayed processing?
- Is there a recommended open source message queue solution that would work for this type of scenario with JSON-based REST web services? Java is preferred as my backend is written in it.
- Are there other techniques I should consider?

Comment: BTW you'd get more answers if you'd make sure your question is really just one question — multiple questions in a question are generally frowned upon.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely correct. I really just wanted confirmation that I was heading down the right path. Thanks for providing this! The other questions were simply to show that I'm also open to any implementation suggestions.

Comment: @Tauren I have an Rest API build in JAX -RS Jersey. I have the same requirment like above. I would be getting the request from the end user and then keeping in message queue. After that I have to send the request one by one to the rest api for processing and response message would be delegating to the end user. I am new for JMS. I had done the Rest API  and after that I am stuck where to start. How to connect Messagequeue with  Rest API. Could you please help me out. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than approach this by focusing on the failure state, it'd be faster and more robust to recognize that these actions should be performed asynchronously and out-of-band from the request by the UI. You should indeed use a message/event/job queue, and just pop those jobs right onto that queue as quickly as possible, and respond to the original request as quickly as possible. Once you've done that, the asynchronous job can be performed independently of the original request, and at its own pace — including with retries as needed.

If you want your API to indicate that there are aspects of the request which have not completed, you can use the HTTP response Status Code `202 (Accepted)`.

Comment: Great advice! This is pretty much how I'm considering doing it, and you're answer has helped confirm I'm on the right track. I'll certainly utilize the `202` code as you suggest.